# Webdriverjs enter REPL from inside code

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to enter into a node REPL at a certain point in the webdriverjs code execution to help debug and troubleshoot issues?

I have some code I'd like to test out but I don't want to run through all the code, and exit.  Instead I'd like to pause the code execution at a given point so that I can see where my commands are failing and figure out how to get it working.

As an example, I have some code to login to a website:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const By = webdriver.By
const until = webdriver.until

var username = "XXX"
var password = "XXX"

function login(username, password) {    
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('Email')))
    driver.findElement(By.id('Email')).sendKeys(username)
    driver.findElement(By.id('next')).click()
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('Passwd')), 5000)
    driver.findElement(By.id('Passwd')).sendKeys(password)

    // open a REPL here to examine elements, try things, etc.

    driver.findElement(By.id('signIn')).click()
}

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome'}).build()
driver.get('https://gmail.com')
login(username, password)
```

I'd like to open a REPL in the above code where the comment is to try out some different things.  I've tried adding `debugger` statements into my code but it doesn't seem to allow the webdriver to step through its code and allow me to interact with webpages at the debug breakpoint, all I can do is look at variables, etc.

Is it possible to step through the code and enter a REPL at a certain point and interact with a webpage?